# How to install and use php 5.6 and 7.0, Arch Linux

Tags: php, linux

I need to install at my systems php v5.6. But present I have php v7.1.3.

How can i roll back my php version to php v5.6 ? Or how to install php v.5.6 together with v.7.1.3 ?

I read this manual
http://blog.schielke.it/posts/92-downgrade-php7-to-php56-on-arch-linux
, installed oldest version, change settings for httpd.conf, command php-v - dispay version 7.1.3 , and php56 -v - display varsion 5.6.30 .
[enter image description here][1]
 But, if I did it :

```
#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp56.so
```

php is not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpcN5.jpg)

My httpd.conf

```
#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp56.so
#AddHandler php7-script php
#Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf
Include conf/extra/php56_module.conf
```

And now, have I fix this problem? Sorry for my english

Comment: You installed php56 cli package. Are you sure that you installed ohp56 apache module?

Comment: I think yes http://imgur.com/IF8LqyGl.png

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `AddHandler php5-script php` on "httpd.conf".

It should look like this:

```
#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp56.so
#AddHandler php7-script php
#Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf
Include conf/extra/php56_module.conf
AddHandler php5-script php
```

You can see that php 5.6 is working by creating a "test.php" file with  `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on it and running "localhost/test.php" on your browser.